# 301 Redirect Directory But Not Its Content

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to redirect mysite.com/blog/ to mysite.com/blogs/. However this redirect should not apply to other pages inside blog directory. For example, mysite.com/blog/article-1 should not redirect to mysite.com/blogs/article-1

First I tried simple 301 redirect but unfortunately it was redirecting all the content. Then I tried the following code but it didn't work out.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.easydestination.net/blogs/ [L,R=301]
```

Any idea how to do it with htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava are you referring to the rule I mentioned in the question? If so I would like to add that it didn't work.

Comment: Make sure that is your first rule and there is no other .htaccess in `/blog/`